# How can I sort a Javascript array alphabetically?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to Sort the people alphabetically by last name. I'm curious if there's a more professional approach to doing that.

My Array :

```
const people = [ 'Bernhard, Sandra', 'Bethea, Erin', 'Becker, Carl', 'Bentsen, Lloyd', 'Beckett, Samuel', 'Blake, William', 'Berger, Ric', 'Beddoes, Mick', 'Beethoven, Ludwig', 'Belloc, Hilaire', 'Begin, Menachem', 'Bellow, Saul', 'Benchley, Robert', 'Blair, Robert', 'Benenson, Peter' ];
```

The code is working properly, but I am confused about why the split method returns inverse values.
Despite asking Poe for help, I am still confused.
The positions of the destructured variables were swapped by Poe when I asked for help but I haven't changed the code yet.

```
const alpha = people.sort((a, b) => {
    const [aFirst, aLast] = a.split(', '); // expected ["Bernhard", "Sandra"] Not [ 'Sandra', 'Bernhard' ]
    const [bFirst, bLast] = b.split(', '); // expected ["Bethea", "Erin"] Not [ 'Erin', 'Bethea' ]
    return aFirst > bFirst ? 1 : -1;
})
console.table(alpha);
```

Comment: `'Bernhard, Sandra'.split(', ')` *is* `['Bernhard', 'Sandra']` and not the other way around. Splitting does not reverse the order.

Comment: Split does not return inverse values.

Comment: If you are sorting by last name, why not just `people.sort()`?

Comment: Your destructuring assignment is putting last name into aFirst and first name into aLast, same for b

Comment: Are we supposed to know who "Poe" is?

Comment: @ mykaf  Not working properly and how can the results be reversed? (z to a)

Comment: @ Scott Marcus https://poe.com/ AI assistant.

Comment: How exactly is `people.sort()` not working properly? You would reverse it with `people.sort.reverse()`

Comment: @Luatic
in return aFirst > bFirst ? 1 : -1;  I used ( aFirst and bFirst ) not ( aLast and bLast ) to make the code work as I wanted.
back to the question:
I want to Sort the people alphabetically by "last name" not a first name.

Comment: @mykaf, Pls, note  I want to Sort the people alphabetically by "last name" not a first name.

Comment: Typically names are formatted *last, first* or *first last* (no comma).
Are your last names *before* or *after* each comma? Assuming before, `Array.sort()` will work just fine. You didn't give an expected output.

Comment: @mykaf 
I've never noticed how names are formatted with commas before. This is a missing point .
You have taught me to look at the final results I expect before asking questions. Your effort is greatly appreciated . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your array already contains strings of names where the last name is the first part of the string, so you can just call the `.sort()` method.

Oh, and your array contains a typo:

`'Blake, 'William'` should be: `'Blake, William'`

```js
const people = [ 'Bernhard, Sandra', 'Bethea, Erin', 'Becker, Carl', 'Bentsen, Lloyd', 'Beckett, Samuel', 'Blake, William', 'Berger, Ric', 'Beddoes, Mick', 'Beethoven, Ludwig', 'Belloc, Hilaire', 'Begin, Menachem', 'Bellow, Saul', 'Benchley, Robert', 'Blair, Robert', 'Benenson, Peter' ];

console.log(people.sort());
```

Comment: @Scoot Marcus, Please note that I want to sort people alphabetically by last name. It's not that simple.
Sorry for the typo. It is a Typo error, but my code is correct. I will edit the question. Thanks for that.

Comment: @AhmadTantawy Given the strings in your array start with the last name, it *is* that simple. What makes you think this doesn't work? What is the expected output, and what output do you get instead when using this approach?

Answer (score 0):

The variables are simply mislabelled, see the following:

```js
const alpha = people.sort((a, b) => {
    const [aLast, aFirst] = a.split(', '); // expected and got ["Bernhard", "Sandra"]
    const [bLast, bFirst] = b.split(', '); // expected and got ["Bethea", "Erin"]
    return aLast > bLast ? 1 : -1;
})
```

Comment: I missed how the sort method works when I tried to console.log a and b inside the sort function. Also, I've never noticed how names are formatted with commas before.
I Appreciate Your effort. Thanks